# I can not see images in GoldenDict!

Tags: package-management

I see a small box and a cross sign in the middle of that in place of images. Anyone having the same issue ?!

Comment: I imagine you talk about Wiki integration. I had this issue with older version. Then I needed to build it from source, as some changes were necessary, due to changes at other party. This was some months ago, thou

Comment: @zetah : Can you tell me the procedure how to build it or can u provide the ready made .deb package you have build.

Comment: Sure, see below

Comment: My situation is the same with Javier. And I did it following you.
But I still cannot see the images(Wikipedia) in GoldenDict.
I saw every step is successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open terminal, then make sample work folder and grab Golden Dict source:

`git clone https://github.com/goldendict/goldendict.git`

Goto cloned folder: `cd goldendict`

Unlike common use, file `configure` lists which packages are needed for building Golden Dict. Get them with `apt-get`:

`sudo apt-get install libvorbis-dev zlib1g-dev libhunspell-dev x11proto-record-dev qt4-qmake libqt4-dev g++ libxtst-dev libphonon-dev`

Now run: `qmake` and then `make`

If everything turns fine, you'll have file `goldendict` in current folder. Then just copy it to preferred folder, and try it:

[image]

Comment: This worked great, thanks! I created a set of monochrome icons for better integration with the ambiance theme. Thought you and future readers might find them helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/193777/how-can-i-convert-a-coloured-icon-to-a-monochrome-one/193805#193805