# How can I convert a coloured icon to a monochrome one?

Tags: themes, icons, indicator, ambiance, goldendict

I recently compiled [goldendict](http://sourceforge.net/projects/goldendict/) from source. To my dismay I discovered that there were no monochrome appindicator icons included. At the moment I am stuck with this:

[image]

I tried converting the icons to B/W using GIMP, but it still doesn't look quite right:

[image]

How can I modify the icons to fit with the rest of the theme?

These are the icons in question:

[image][image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I invested some time and did it myself. What I did was basically use GIMP's *Alpha to Selection* tool to select the non-transparent parts of the image. Then I chose the *Bucket Fill* tool to apply a homogenous grey colour to the icon. All other refinements I did manually with the *Paintbrush* tool.

These are the raw icons:

[image: programicon_old.png] (programicon_old.png) [image: programicon_scan.png] (programicon_scan.png)

This is what the indicator now looks like:

[image]

In order to install the icons you will have to compile GoldenDict from source:

- Clone the GitHub repository

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/goldendict/goldendict.git
  ```
- Navigate to `./goldendict/icons` and replace `programicon_old.png` and `programicon_scan.png` with the updated icons
- Follow the instructions in `README.md` to compile and install GoldenDict