# How to apply mono effect in my icon?

Tags: system-tray, image-editor

So my icon is the lizard ( the first one in the tray )

[image: icon-no-mono]

If i open the dash there is an automatic mono effect to all the icons in the tray

[image: icon-mono]

So i am wondering how can i edit my icon ( with an image editing software ), to make it mono, so it is more ubuntu-native..

Comment: [This post might help you](http://askubuntu.com/questions/193777/how-can-i-convert-a-coloured-icon-to-a-monochrome-one).